# Delete to EOL without entering insert mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste, normal-mode

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Bunch of text      trailing...
Bunch of text      trailing... 
Bunch of text      trailing...
Bunch of text      trailing...
Bunch of text      trailing...
```

I can use <kbd>C</kbd> to remove the `trailing...` text, but that puts me into **insert mode**; Is there a way to delete to the end of the line without leaving **normal mode**?

Comment: What do you mean by kill? Is `d$` what you're looking for?

Comment: Seems like an easy find in the man page

Comment: Actually, I would suggest to go through `vimtutor` ;)

Comment: @grodzik soz, it's a term from the heretical Emacs: it's the same thing as clearing to EOL.

Comment: @grodzik @DoritoStyle I was using vim on my phone; I don't know if the app supports `vimtutor`; I'm pretty sure it doesn't offer man pages, though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. You want to use the "delete" operator instead of the "Change" operator. The delete operator is

```
d<motion>
```

and it deletes everything that `<motion>` moves over.

In this case, the motion you want is `$` which moves to the end of the current line. Of course, you may also use `D` which is simply a shortcut for `d$`